# raster::rasterize set wrong values with enclosed polygons

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, rasterization

Similarly to this post

[rasterize (R package raster) fail to rasterize island polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181408/rasterize-r-package-raster-fail-to-rasterize-island-polygons)

the `rasterize` function in the `raster` package is giving me problems with enclosed polygons. In my case, some enclosed polygons are rasterized with cell values equal to the enclosing polygons, as they were somehow 'merged'.

Here's my sample code

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
require(rgeos)
require(raster)

## set wd
wd <- 'M:/foo'
setwd(wd)

## open shapefile
sample.poly <- readOGR(dsn=wd, layer='sample')

## rasterize
resol <- 10
r <- raster(res=resol, ext=extent(sample.poly))
sample.r <- rasterize(sample.poly, r, 'Code') 

## export files
writeRaster(x=sample.r, filename='sample.tif', format='GTiff')
writeOGR(obj=sample.poly, dsn=wd, layer='sample', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Here's the structure of table of attributes

```
str(sample.poly@data)
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  2 variables:
$ OBJECTID: num  6249 14593 14614 15434 15683 ...
$ Code    : int  33200 32110 33300 32410 32210 31210 33300 32110 32210 31210 ..
```

`data$Code` are CORINE LCM-like codes. I already tried to set them as characters instead of integers, but the same error occurred.

Here's how the sample shapefile looks like (in QGIS)

[image]

and here's the result of `rasterize`

[image]

As you can see, the enclosed polygon marked with yellow arrow is properly rasterized, while the one marked with the red arrow is 'dissolved' in the enclosing polygon.

Any suggestion? Is it a bug? This is just a sample taken from a larger shapefile, with dozens of such errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug but an expected behavior. Note that `rasterize` takes a `fun` argument that handles grid cells with two or more values. By default it uses that `last` function, namely the value that appears last on the data data.frame is used. Similarly `first` will use the value that appears first. Other functions include `count`, `mean`, etc.

Here is a short example with a proposed solution. In short, if you are able to sort the shape file features by their area from smallest to largest, the `first` function promise to get all islands rasterized.

[image: QGIS vector with islands]

The data is given here; islands are in bold.

> str(shape@data)
>   'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
>    $ id  : int  1 2 **3** **4**
>    $ type: int  1 2 **2** **1**

Using the `first` function, as in: `r2first <- rasterize(shape, r, "type", fun = "first")` does not rasterize the islands, since they appear last in the attribute table.

[image: Islands are not being rasterized]

The following code fixes the problem:

`area <- sapply(1:nrow(shape), function(x) {shape@polygons[[x]]@Polygons[[1]]@area}) 
shape1 <- shape[order(area), ]
r2first_1 <- rasterize(shape1, r, "type", fun = "first")
plot(r2first_1)`

[image]

The idea of using area as the sort criteria is that islands must be smaller that their accommodating polygons.

Comment: Thank you, it works indeed! I thought that `fun` argument applied just to cells shared by two polygons and not to 'core' cells, so it extends its effect to all polygon, right?

Comment: `fun` is applied to cells shared by two polygons. If your data was topologically-correct than there shouldn't be a problem. However, islands in the common "spaghetti" model are an overlay of two polygons. The solution just sort the data in a way effective to prioritize islands in any case of an overlay.